# Animation in WPF showing images one by one

Tags: wpf, animation

I would like to create something like this 
animateit.net/categories.php?cat_id=218&page=11 - 
Frog Gets Spider Animated Gif ...

I have a frog image, a tongue image and a bug image separate, but not able to put it in animation using WPF.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are you displaying the images? Are you attempting to do this in the XAML or the code-behind? You need to clarify what you've done and what you're trying to do before we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to animate an image in the code-behind, you'll set it up something like this:

MyImage is where you're displaying the "gif".
FrogImage is the image of just the frog.
TongueImage is the image of the tongue coming out.
BugImage is the image of the frog with the bug.

First, initialize a timer like this, perhaps in 'MainWindow()' or at the global level:

```
DispatcherTimer tmrBlinkImage = new DispatcherTimer()
            { IsEnabled = false, Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500) };
tmrBlinkImage.Tick += new EventHandler(tmrBlinkImage_Tick);
public int _ImageBlinkIndex = 0;
```

Then, set up the event handler like this:

```
private void tmrBlinkImage_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (null == MyImage)
            return;

        if (MyImage.IsDisposed)
            return;

        switch (_ImageBlinkIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                if (MyImage.Source != FrogImage)
                    MyImage.Source = FrogImage;

                _ImageBlinkIndex++;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (MyImage.Source != TongueImage)
                    MyImage.Source = TongueImage;

                _ImageBlinkIndex++;

                break;
            case 2:
                if (MyImage.Source != BugImage)
                    MyImage.Source = BugImage;

                _ImageBlinkIndex = 0;
                break;
            default:
                _ImageBlinkIndex = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tmrBlinkImage.Stop();
        //woops....
    }
}
```

This will cycle through the images and update the frame every half second. Adjust the values as you best see fit.